# gvNIX datatables set sorting options table (which fields)

Tags: datatables, spring-roo, gvnix

How can I specify the sorting of a datatable with gvNIX datatables?
And example based on the Petclinic sample would be great.

For my application I want for each table specify the sorting order of the records in the datatables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lock at options supported in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/datatables/column.tagx` the attributes `sortInit` and `sortDirection` should help you.

```
<jsp:directive.attribute name="sortInit" 
      type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true"
      description="(asc|desc) If sortable is enabled, set the default sorting direction (Default : asc)" />
<jsp:directive.attribute name="sortDirection" 
      type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true"
      description="((asc|desc)[,(asc|desc)[...]])If sortable is enabled, allow to control the sorting direction(s) (default 'asc,desc') (related to asSorting js-datatables columnDef)" />
```

By example, on *list.jspx*:

```
    <table:table data="${pets}" id="l_com_springsource_petclinic_domain_Pet" path="/pets" z="gvs425syhOX//lJjxIylimFQflM=">
        <table:column id="c_com_springsource_petclinic_domain_Pet_sendReminders"
            property="sendReminders" z="9OZRH4z6dmoKcOlx/Gs0++zdd/A="/>
        <table:column id="c_com_springsource_petclinic_domain_Pet_name" 
            property="name" sortInit="asc" z="USER-MANAGED"/>
        <table:column id="c_com_springsource_petclinic_domain_Pet_weight" property="weight" z="sDq86anRDnXzji8d7j+tb9X7coI="/>
        ....
        ....
    </table:table>
```

I advise you to review all *.tagx* files. Its parameters will show you all supported options and features you can use.

Good luck!